# Application switcher for KDE

Tags: kde, window-manager

I'm searching for application switcher for KDE - something that allows me to type in partial name of window (title).

Is there anything like that? For windows there is nice utility - Switcher.

Comment: You may like to try this:- http://hanschen.org/2011/05/15/7-ways-to-switch-activities/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**krunner**. Default open command is **Alt+F2**. You can use the settings dialog to enable the  *Windows* plugin which does exactly what you're asking. I assume you are on KDE4.